# What causes MySQL not to enforce NOT NULL constraint?

Tags: mysql

The following query surprised me and didn't fail, but inserted a record.

```
INSERT INTO buy_contacts(buys_id,contacts_id,buy_status,sites_id,record_status,date_modified,date_created)
VALUES(863999180,1367026068,"buy",2675631760,"active",NOW(),NOW());
```

A SELECT query shows it as being inserted.

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
|  buys_id  | contacts_id | notes |  date_modified  |  date_created   | record_status |  sites_id  | buy_status | created_by_id | modified_by_id |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
| 863999180 |  1367026068 | NULL  | 1/10/2015 10:31 | 1/10/2015 10:31 | active        | 2675631760 | buy        |             0 |              0 |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
```

My table schema (created by MySQL Workbench) is shown below.  As seen, `created_by_id` and `modified_by_id` are both `NOT NULL`, do not have a `DEFAULT` value, and the query that inserted the record did not include these columns.

Why didn't MySQL reject the query due to a NOT NULL constraint and why did it insert values of zero for these columns?

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

// other tables are created...

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buy_contacts` (
  `buys_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `contacts_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `notes` TEXT NULL,
  `date_modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `record_status` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `sites_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `buy_status` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `created_by_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `modified_by_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`buys_id`, `contacts_id`),
  INDEX `fk_buys_has_contacts_contacts1_idx` (`contacts_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_buys_has_contacts_buys1_idx` (`buys_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_buy_contacts_record_status2_idx` (`record_status` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_buy_contacts_sites2_idx` (`sites_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_buy_contacts_buy_status1_idx` (`buy_status` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_buy_contacts_users1_idx` (`created_by_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_buy_contacts_users2_idx` (`modified_by_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_buys_has_contacts_buys1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`buys_id`)
    REFERENCES `buys` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_buys_has_contacts_contacts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contacts_id`)
    REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_buy_contacts_record_status2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`record_status`)
    REFERENCES `record_status` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_buy_contacts_sites2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sites_id`)
    REFERENCES `sites` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_buy_contacts_buy_status1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`buy_status`)
    REFERENCES `buy_status` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_buy_contacts_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_buy_contacts_users2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`modified_by_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: _In MySQL an explicit NULL may also represent the next value of a pseudo-sequence and an implicit NULL may represent an implicit default value (a zero or empty string) determined by MySQL._  http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html#1_1

Comment: 1/10/2015 10:31 - How did that happen?

Comment: MySQL gotchas!  Definitely a gotcha.  Would never have expected that.  Couldn't find it in the MySQL official documentation.

Comment: @Strawberry  I inputted the output into Excel so I could use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to make a pretty table.  Must have been changed.  Good attention to detail!

Comment: @Sathya  I thought I had MySQL configured under Strict mode, but not sure for this particular issue.  Is it possible to configure MySQL to not attempt to be so smart and reject the insert?

Comment: @user1032531 I'm not sure - I'm not well versed with MySQL, but had read about this earlier, so pointed it out!

Comment: @Sathya.  Well, all I could say is "Thank You"!  This was driving me crazy.

Comment: Check an sql_mode using `select @@sql_mode`. If you want to get an error in the insert, you need to enable either `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` mode =>  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables

Comment: @kordirko.  I am currently using `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 
innodb_strict_mode=on 
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`.  I will check out `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`

Comment: @kordirko.  Changing to `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` did the trick.  Not sure, however, if there are some negative implications if single-row statements are not implemented.

Comment: Can you mark this question as answered please, since it is.

Comment: I don't seem any null values from your query,except the note,which is nullable by your table definition. For the two ids,you didn't provide valid values,and mysql fulfill its promise and inserted the default values for int. It's normal behavior based on your mysql current configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have STRICT_ALL_TABLES mode enabled and you have version 5.6 installed.

By default, MySQL uses obsolete "tolerant" mode, which was needed for non-transaction storage engines (MyISAM).